# Selenium Python : eliminating text from child element using find_element_by_css_selector() method

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, methods, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

In Selenium using Python, I have been trying to select text from a DIV selector which has a child element as well.The code looks like this:-

```
<div class="empty-cart-message">
 There are no items in this cart.<br>
<button class="btn btn-blue close continue-button continue-empty-btn tmargin10">Continue Shopping</button> 
</div>
```

I need the text "There are no items in this cart." only , and I am using `find_element_by_css_selector()` method.

The problem that I am facing is that apart from the text I need, it also gets the text inside button tag. The code I am using looks like this:-

```
cart_status=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.empty-cart-message").text

if(assertEqual("There are no items in this cart", cart_status)):
   cont_btn=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.continue-empty-bin")
   cont_btn.click()
```

I am not able to find anything that can eliminate/deselect "Button's" text directly from the method I am using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xpath:

```
//div[@class='empty-cart-message' ]/child::text()
```

but, currently selenium doesn't support object(because it is not a webelement), you can run by Python javascript executor:

```
returnText = driver.execute_script("return  document.evaluate(\"//div[@class='empty-cart-message']/child::text()\", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;")
```

Comment: As told by @mahsum-akbas (his answer above) , I tried using javascript executor.But, the **method** `driver.execute_script()` returned **no value**

Comment: i tried same html and python in my local and, can see text in output.

Comment: I did the same @mahsum-akbas !! The script is running without showing any error but the `execute_script()` is returning a blank **String**. Does it require to be tested on a specific version of **Selenium or Python or any different browser** that you might be using ?